# What happens to selenium code simulating browser actiions when run in non GUI unix box? Will chrome windows open?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, unix

I built my first selenium on a mac machine, so with help of chromedriver, I see a new tab opened by my script.

1. What happens when chromedriver and selenium is run on a unix
   machine with no GUI?
2. Will the script still run and produce
   results?
3. Let's say if my script had opened multiple windows, over
   span of multiple days, how to close all the open windows/tabs after
   a while?

Comment: 1) You probably need to run the driver as "headless".  This is a no-GUI browser.  2) It should with headless option.  Browser still needs to be installed, though.  3) When you quit the driver it should close all open windows/tabs associated with it.

Comment: @pcalkins THanks a ton. Please post it as an answer.